# Estimate the flux of a vector field based on its divergence.

Tags: multivariable-calculus

A smooth vector field $\bf{F}$ has $\nabla\cdot \mathbf{F}(−4,−1,−5)=6$. Estimate the flux of $\mathbf F$ out of a small sphere of radius $r=0.28$ centered at the point $(−4,−1,−5)$.

Comment: Have you tried?

Answer (score 1):

From the Divergence Theorem, we know that

$$
flux = \iiint_D \nabla \cdot \vec F \ dV
$$

If we assume that the flux is uniform throughout the sphere (which is a decent approximation since we only know the flux at the center), $\nabla \cdot \vec F$ is constant and it follows that

$$
flux \approx \left( \nabla \cdot \vec F\right) \iiint_D dV
$$

$$
=6 \left( \frac{4}{3}\pi r^3 \right)
$$

$$
= 8\pi r^3
$$

$$
= 8\pi(0.28)^3
$$

$$
= 0.552
$$

Answer (score 0):

flux=$\int_V \nabla. \textbf{F}$ d$V$

because we can assume the divergence to be constant within the volume, we get:

flux=$\nabla. \textbf{F} \frac{4}{3} \pi r^3=0.5517$

Comment: thanks for the negative comment. Any feedback will be welcomed. Love to all